# Accessing a dictionary within a list within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
user = code.chan["#example"]["Someuser"]
# user would look something like:
{
    'normal': True,
    'voiced': False,
    'op': False,
    'count': 24,
    'messages': [
        {
            'time': 1448847813,
            'message': "This is my mesage"
        },
        {
            'time': 1448847818,
            'message': "And this is another"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get put the items in 'message' into a list to check whether a string matches any of the items.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Am I not understanding or is your question trivial? `theList = user["messages"]`. Please provide your expected result

Comment: `user['messages']` is a list; what items in that list were you trying to put into a separate list?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want this:

```
print [i['message'] for i in user['messages']]
```

Or,

```
print map(lambda x:x['message'],user['messages'])
```

Output:

```
['This is my mesage', 'And this is another']
```

To print only the last item, you can use negative indexing. Just like below:

```
print [i['message'] for i in user['messages']][-1]
```

Output:

```
And this is another
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've used this, and it works, but now my question extends to "How do get the last item only?"

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. It seems I can't access 'time' with this method. Is there something else I should try?

Comment: Actually you could, `print [i['time'] for i in user['messages']][-1]`

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like so:

```
for message in user['messages']:
    if some_string == message['message']:
        match = True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to search through them you'd want to do something like;

```
if any(search_string in i['message'] for i in user['messages']):
    print 'found your query'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i am a bit confused by the question but if i imagined correctly here is my answer.

You have a list of lists and i suspect it is in json format so you need to access it like this

```
#fetch data 
r = requests.get(wherever_you_fetch_them)
s = r.content.decode()
json_resp = json.loads(s)

succ = json_resp['messages']['message']
```

and you can create a loop, but i cant help you more because i don't know any information about input data.